# Styling multiple custom wordpress logins

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make a separate login for a subdomain of a website. I have added the following into my template .php file, which just creates the user pass fields and the login button:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

in the wordpress documentation, it says that the styling of this form is done in "your active Theme's stylesheet (style.css)". I have added a typical template online into my style sheet but its not loading it. I am not sure if i have added in the right section or if the classes are different when you call the login form this way. A snippet of my styling code is below:

```css
body.login {
  background-image: url('bg_piece.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}.login h1 a {
  background-image: url('logo.png');
}
.login label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555555;
}

.login input[type="text"]{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color:#dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.login input[type="password"]{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color:#dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}.login .button-primary {
  width: 120px;
  float:right;
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#17a8e3), to(#17a8e3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #17a8e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3 0%, #17a8e3 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #0d9ed9;
}

.login .button-primary:hover {
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#17a8e3), to(#0d9ed9 ));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #17a8e3, #0d9ed9 );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0b436e 0%, #0d9ed9 100%);
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #0d9ed9;
}

.login .button-primary:active {
  background-color:#17a8e3 !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0d9ed9), to(#17a8e3));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9, #17a8e3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0d9ed9 0%, #17a8e3 100%);
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1
```

I have tried to put it in different .css forms and that doesn't seem to work. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check open and close {} current.
Use the images files are used in the same folder --you used in code .png

.CSS

```
body.login { background-image: url('bg_piece.png'); 
             background-repeat: repeat; 
             background-attachment: fixed; 
             background-position: center; 
           }

.login h1 a { background-image: url('logo.png'); }
```

Comment: I don't think the CSS is the problem. I put the style.css file in the same folder as the template but wp login form isnt utilising the .css file

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your login function in a div like

```
<div class="my-cust-login"><?php wp_login_form(); ?></div>
```

If your login form is showing, you can now target your fields with that class like

```
.my-cust-login .login h1 a{
background:red;
}
```

Clear your caches by the way, if you have any caching plugin.